# find users and permission on database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write a query on a sql that will report all the users that have access to a specific database, or objects within the database such as tables, views, and stored procedures, either directly or due to roles.

I have a code that gives the correct output when executed alone.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseUserName VARCHAR(50); -- ='user'
DECLARE @LoginName VARCHAR(50); -- ='login'

 SELECT [UserType] = CASE princ.[type] WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                                         WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                                         WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group' END
              , [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name]
              , [LoginName] = ulogin.[name]
              , [Role] = NULL
              , [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name]
              , [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc]
              , [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc] -- Schema-contained objects
                                         ELSE perm.[class_desc] -- Higher-level objects
                                     END
              , [Schema] = objschem.[name]
              , [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name] -- Schemas
                                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name] -- Impersonations
                                         ELSE OBJECT_NAME (perm.[major_id]) -- General objects
                                     END
              , [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Database user
                sys.database_principals AS princ
    --Login accounts
    LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS ulogin ON ulogin.[sid] = princ.[sid]
    --Permissions
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS objschem ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
    --Table columns
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS col ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                   AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
    --Impersonations
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals AS imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE princ.[type] IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' )
                -- No need for these system accounts
                AND princ.[name] NOT IN ( 'sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' )
                AND (princ.[name] = @DatabaseUserName OR @DatabaseUserName IS NULL) 
                AND (ulogin.[name] = @LoginName OR @LoginName IS NULL)
    UNION

    --2) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group through a database or application role
    SELECT [UserType] = CASE membprinc.[type] WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                                         WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                                         WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group' END
              , [DatabaseUserName] = membprinc.[name]
              , [LoginName] = ulogin.[name]
              , [Role] = roleprinc.[name]
              , [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name]
              , [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc]
              , [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc] -- Schema-contained objects
                                         ELSE perm.[class_desc] -- Higher-level objects
                                     END
              , [Schema] = objschem.[name]
              , [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name] -- Schemas
                                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name] -- Impersonations
                                         ELSE OBJECT_NAME (perm.[major_id]) -- General objects
                                     END
              , [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Role/member associations
                sys.database_role_members AS members
    --Roles
    JOIN sys.database_principals AS roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
    --Role members (database users)
    JOIN sys.database_principals AS membprinc ON membprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
    --Login accounts
    LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS ulogin ON ulogin.[sid] = membprinc.[sid]
    --Permissions
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS objschem ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
    --Table columns
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS col ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
    --Impersonations
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals AS imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE membprinc.[type] IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' )
                -- No need for these system accounts
                AND membprinc.[name] NOT IN ( 'sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' )
                AND (membprinc.[name] = @DatabaseUserName OR @DatabaseUserName IS NULL)
                AND (ulogin.[name] = @LoginName OR @LoginName IS NULL)
    UNION

    --3) List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
    SELECT [UserType] = '{All Users}'
              , [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}'
              , [LoginName] = '{All Users}'
              , [Role] = roleprinc.[name]
              , [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name]
              , [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc]
              , [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc] -- Schema-contained objects
                                         ELSE perm.[class_desc] -- Higher-level objects
                                     END
              , [Schema] = objschem.[name]
              , [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name] -- Schemas
                                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name] -- Impersonations
                                         ELSE OBJECT_NAME (perm.[major_id]) -- General objects
                                     END
              , [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Roles
                sys.database_principals AS roleprinc
    --Role permissions
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
    --All objects
    JOIN sys.objects AS obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS objschem ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
    --Table columns
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS col ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                   AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
    --Impersonations
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals AS imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE roleprinc.[type] = 'R'
                AND roleprinc.[name] = 'public'
                AND obj.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
                AND (roleprinc.[name] = @DatabaseUserName OR @DatabaseUserName IS NULL)


    ORDER BY [UserType]
              , [DatabaseUserName]
              , [LoginName]
              , [Role]
              , [Schema]
              , [ObjectName]
              , [ColumnName]
              , [PermissionType]
              , [PermissionState]
              , [ObjectType];
```

Now I want to run this code for all databases. But when I execute this command, it does not output anything

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DatabaseUserName VARCHAR(50); -- ='user'
DECLARE @LoginName VARCHAR(50); -- ='login'

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_OVERVIEW
(
  DatabaseName     VARCHAR(128)  NOT NULL
, UserType         VARCHAR(13)   NULL
, DatabaseUserName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
, LoginName        NVARCHAR(128) NULL
, Role             NVARCHAR(128) NULL
, PermissionType   NVARCHAR(128) NULL
, PermissionState  NVARCHAR(60)  NULL
, ObjectType       NVARCHAR(60)  NULL
, [Schema]         sys.sysname   NULL
, ObjectName       NVARCHAR(128) NULL
, ColumnName       sys.sysname   NULL
);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
      name
FROM  master.sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'msdb', 'model', 'tempdb')
      AND state_desc = 'online';

OPEN db_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
INTO
  @DatabaseName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT
    @SqlCommand = N'USE ' + @DatabaseName + N';' +
'INSERT INTO #TEMP_OVERVIEW
SELECT ' + @DatabaseName + ', t.*
FROM (SELECT      [UserType]         = CASE princ.[type] WHEN ''S'' THEN ''SQL User''
                                         WHEN ''U'' THEN ''Windows User''
                                         WHEN ''G'' THEN ''Windows Group'' END
              , [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name]
              , [LoginName]        = ulogin.[name]
              , [Role]             = NULL
              , [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name]
              , [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc]
              , [ObjectType]       = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc] -- Schema-contained objects
                                         ELSE perm.[class_desc]                    -- Higher-level objects
                                     END
              , [Schema]           = objschem.[name]
              , [ObjectName]       = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name] -- Schemas
                                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]                     -- Impersonations
                                         ELSE OBJECT_NAME (perm.[major_id])         -- General objects
                                     END
              , [ColumnName]       = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Database user
                sys.database_principals  AS princ
    --Login accounts
    LEFT JOIN   sys.server_principals    AS ulogin ON ulogin.[sid] = princ.[sid]
    --Permissions
    LEFT JOIN   sys.database_permissions AS perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.objects              AS obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas              AS objschem ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
    --Table columns
    LEFT JOIN   sys.columns              AS col ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                   AND   col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
    --Impersonations
    LEFT JOIN   sys.database_principals  AS imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE       princ.[type] IN ( ''S'', ''U'', ''G'' )
                -- No need for these system accounts
                AND princ.[name] NOT IN ( ''sys'', ''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'' )
                AND (princ.[name] = '+@DatabaseUserName+' OR  '+@DatabaseUserName+' IS NULL)            
                AND (ulogin.[name] = '+@LoginName+' OR  '+@LoginName+' IS NULL)
    UNION

    --2) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group through a database or application role
    SELECT      [UserType]         = CASE membprinc.[type] WHEN ''S'' THEN ''SQL User''
                                         WHEN ''U'' THEN ''Windows User''
                                         WHEN ''G'' THEN ''Windows Group'' END
              , [DatabaseUserName] = membprinc.[name]
              , [LoginName]        = ulogin.[name]
              , [Role]             = roleprinc.[name]
              , [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name]
              , [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc]
              , [ObjectType]       = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc] -- Schema-contained objects
                                         ELSE perm.[class_desc]                    -- Higher-level objects
                                     END
              , [Schema]           = objschem.[name]
              , [ObjectName]       = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name] -- Schemas
                                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]                     -- Impersonations
                                         ELSE OBJECT_NAME (perm.[major_id])         -- General objects
                                     END
              , [ColumnName]       = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Role/member associations
                sys.database_role_members AS members
    --Roles
    JOIN        sys.database_principals   AS roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
    --Role members (database users)
    JOIN        sys.database_principals   AS membprinc ON membprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
    --Login accounts
    LEFT JOIN   sys.server_principals     AS ulogin ON ulogin.[sid] = membprinc.[sid]
    --Permissions
    LEFT JOIN   sys.database_permissions  AS perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas               AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.objects               AS obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas               AS objschem ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
    --Table columns
    LEFT JOIN   sys.columns               AS col ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                    AND   col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
    --Impersonations
    LEFT JOIN   sys.database_principals   AS imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE       membprinc.[type] IN ( ''S'', ''U'', ''G'' )
                -- No need for these system accounts
                AND membprinc.[name] NOT IN ( ''sys'', ''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'' )
                AND (membprinc.[name] = '+@DatabaseUserName+' OR  '+@DatabaseUserName+' IS NULL)
                AND (ulogin.[name] = '+ @LoginName +' OR  '+@LoginName+' IS NULL)
    UNION

    --3) List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
    SELECT      [UserType]         = ''{All Users}''
              , [DatabaseUserName] = ''{All Users}''
              , [LoginName]        = ''{All Users}''
              , [Role]             = roleprinc.[name]
              , [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name]
              , [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc]
              , [ObjectType]       = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc] -- Schema-contained objects
                                         ELSE perm.[class_desc]                    -- Higher-level objects
                                     END
              , [Schema]           = objschem.[name]
              , [ObjectName]       = CASE perm.[class] WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name] -- Schemas
                                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]                     -- Impersonations
                                         ELSE OBJECT_NAME (perm.[major_id])         -- General objects
                                     END
              , [ColumnName]       = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Roles
                sys.database_principals  AS roleprinc
    --Role permissions
    LEFT JOIN   sys.database_permissions AS perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
    --All objects
    JOIN        sys.objects              AS obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
    LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas              AS objschem ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
    --Table columns
    LEFT JOIN   sys.columns              AS col ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                   AND   col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
    --Impersonations
    LEFT JOIN   sys.database_principals  AS imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE       roleprinc.[type] = ''R''
                AND roleprinc.[name] = ''public''
                AND obj.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
                AND (roleprinc.[name] = '+ @DatabaseUserName +' OR  '+ @DatabaseUserName +' IS NULL)) AS t
' 

  EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand;

  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
  INTO
    @DatabaseName;
END

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

SELECT
      *
FROM  #TEMP_OVERVIEW
WHERE DatabaseUserName = @DatabaseUserName
      AND LoginName = @LoginName
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because @SqlCommand's value is null or variables and string concatenation for where conditions.

string + null will become null in t-sql.

Some variable's value is null,  like  @LoginName ...

You can add **print isnull(@SqlCommand, '@SqlCommand is Null');** before EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand; to check t-sql

Comment: What can I do to get the output?

Comment: #TEMP_OVERVIEW should be global temp table? 
```sql
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DatabaseUserName VARCHAR(50)='';
DECLARE @LoginName VARCHAR(50)='';

/..../
print @SqlCommand;
--EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand;

```
You can check t-sql

Comment: Rainmaker Thank you very much for trying to solve my problem.

Yes, that table must be global so that the outputs can be inserted.

 Apply the changes as you said, but everything goes wrong